# MySQL: select multiple rows which has specific field value

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm having a users_conversations table contains a conversation_id and a user_id to tell which users are in the same conversation. I want to find any conversation_id which has user_id 76 and user_id 146 (which are ids 28, 31 and 32. These ids are not unknown to me. I just have both users ids) I tried

```
select * from users_conversations where user_id = 146 or user_id = 76 GROUP BY conversation_id
```

but I get

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'forums.users_conversations.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the table for these users, `group by conversation_id` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select conversation_id
from users_conversations
where user_id in (76, 146)
group by conversation_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2
```

You may omit `distinct` if there is no case of duplicate users for each `conversation_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from users_conversations
where conversations_id in (select conversations_id from user_conversations where user_id=76) 
AND conversations_id in (select conversations_id from user_conversations where user_id=146)
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean instead:

```
select * from users_conversations where user_id = 146 or user_id = 76
```

Why do you want to use group?

Comment: this will list all conversations having user_id = 146 or user_id = 76 which means all their conversations with other users. I want their conversations together which are the 3 ids I added in the question